# Why I'm getting ORA-00979 while trying to use LISTAGG and LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, left-join, listagg

I'm trying to `group` my results so, instead of looking like this:

```
id  | nome  |  bairro
---------------------
1 . |Test 1 | bairro 1
1 . |Test 1 | bairro 2
2 . |Test 2 | bairro 3
```

It looks like this:

```
id  | nome  |  bairro
----------------------
1 . |Test 1 | bairro 1, bairro 2
2 . |Test 2 | bairro 3
```

The 'id' and 'nome' are in table 1 and 'bairro' is in `table 3` in the column 'nome'.

**table 1**

```
id  | nome  | situacao
--------------------
1 . |Test 1 | EM_ATIVIDADE
2 . |Test 2 | EM_ATIVIDADE
```

**table 2**

```
id  | escola (fgk table 1) | bairro (fgk table 3)
-------------------------------------------------
1 . | 2                    | 1
2 . | 2                    | 2
```

**table 3**

```
id  | nome     
---------------
1 . | bairro 1 
2 . | bairro 2
```

I'm trying to do it using `LISTAGG` with the code below:

```
SELECT table1.nome, table1.id, LISTAGG(table3.nome, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table3.nome) as "bairro"
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.escola = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.id = table2.bairro
WHERE table1.situacao = 'EM_ATIVIDADE'
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.nome
ORDER BY table1.id
```

When I do it, I get the error

> ORA-00979: not a group by expression

Can someone help me? I'm a beginner

*edit*: Already tried adding `table1.nome` to my group by.

Comment: Just add table1.nome to your group by

Comment: Just did, keeps the same error (ORA-00979)

Comment: table2.nome should be table3.nome in LISTAGG

Comment: Thank you again! But it actually is, I typed wrong when changing the real table name to table 1, 2, 3. I will correct this on the question tho.

Comment: Your query as you have it now after the edits works for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00044c52b3660ffa3597c760cb5fdc85

Comment: You should put your code into https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler Would make it quicker for others to solve/give you correct answer.

Comment: That's weird, if it is working in dbfiggle that means I have a problem with my db or the way the table was made??

Comment: When try with ta table you created (table1, table2 and table3) it works here too. But when I try with the real tables in my db it does not work :(

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with code questions. Also this is an easily googled duplicate--either via the error message or via a clear statement of what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're using an aggregating function which returns a single row, alongside columns which will return multiple rows.  So you either need to group every "normal" column in your GROUP BY clause, or apply some aggregating function to the values from the "normal" columns, such as MIN, MAX, SUM, etc.

In your example, it would be something like

```
SELECT table1.nome, table1.id, LISTAGG(table2.nome, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table2.nome) as "bairro"
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.escola = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.id = table2.bairro
WHERE table1.situacao = 'EM_ATIVIDADE'
GROUP BY table1.nome, table1.id
ORDER BY table1.id
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(table1.nome), MAX(table1.id), LISTAGG(table2.nome, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table2.nome) as "bairro"
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.escola = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.id = table2.bairro
WHERE table1.situacao = 'EM_ATIVIDADE'
ORDER BY table1.id
```

There is an alternative, which is to use the

```
OVER (partition BY <column name here>)
```

clause, e.g. something like

```
SELECT table1.nome, table1.id, LISTAGG(table3.nome, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table3.nome) OVER (PARTITION BY table1.id) as "bairro"
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.escola = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.id = table2.bairro
WHERE table1.situacao = 'EM_ATIVIDADE'
ORDER BY table1.id
```

See the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code to the following;

```
SELECT table1.nome, table1.id, LISTAGG(table1.nome, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY table1.nome, table1.id) as "bairro"
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.escola = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.id = table2.bairro
WHERE table1.situacao = 'EM_ATIVIDADE'
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.nome
ORDER BY table1.id, table1.nome
```

I added all of your non-LISTAGG selected columns in `GROUP BY` and I also added them inside your `LISTAGG's ORDER BY` clause.

Other then that, I also added `table1.nome` to `ORDER BY` of your whole query, as I figured out it would be visibly better after execution.

I hope I helped!